# Image link to one JS code also invoking a second in error

Tags: php, javascript

I'm a bit stumped here! I have a page with two image links, one which slides up a div from the bottom of the screen (see code 1 below), and a second which shows a hidden div (see code 2). Independantly they both work a treat, but when on the same page, when clicking the link to show the hidden div, Code 1 seems to be invoked too, sliding up the div from the bottom.

The link to slide the div works fine on that page.

I'm not sure it it's important, but the page is a php document, with Code 1 part of one page, and Code 2 & the HTML below part of an extra document called via php include. Hope that makes sense

**Code 1**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({top:'128px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({top:'1083px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
</script>
```

**Code 2**

```
<script>
function show() {
    if(document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display=='none') {
      document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display='block';
    }
}    
</script>
```

**HTML - this is the problem link**

```
<div class="clear_list_button" >
<a href="#1" name="1" onclick="show();">
<img src="images/transparent.png" width="315" height="100" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `#clickme` on the page? Could you expand the html to display that in relation to the problem link?

Comment: #clickme is an empty div on the first php page (I suppose what Id call the container as a newby). There's nothing in it. I'll send a link to the actual page for demonstration purposes....

Comment: http://www.elbowroom.eu/ship_image/shipinfo2.php?# click trolley top right corner to show a info request form, the problem link is the green box - ps this is designed for firefox

Comment: Is it normal that part of the page is off-screen ?

Comment: yeah, basically it's for a museum, and not the net, high res on a large screen. The glossary part is hidden at the bottom. Really can't find a way to stop this happening - please help

Comment: where is the clear_list_button? I can find it in the source, but not while inspecting element.

Comment: the clear list button is the green block - I did this to identify it.... party because it is located close to the glossary link, so thought I might be hitting the wrong one, but no!

Comment: Whatever is logging numbers in the console is making this really annoying to debug

Comment: Sorry Joe, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to use the chrome console, and it's hard to type with the console.log(interval) line popping up ever second

Comment: please do suggest if there's anything I can alter to make it easier

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the "glossary" pane is sliding up. It is not. Your entire page viewport is scrolling down.

It is because of this:

```
<a href="#1"
```

The `#1` anchor is further down the page. The link takes you to it, effectively scrolling the page down for you. To stop that from happening, `return false` at the end of `show` function.

```
function show() {
    if(document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display=='none') {
      document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display='block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

**edit** better functionality would be this:

```
function show(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display=='none') {
      document.getElementById('clear_list_wrapperID').style.display='block';
    }
}
```

See here for explanation of preventDefault: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events

---

**edit**

Turns out the problem can be avoided by changing `<a href="#1"` to `<a href="#"`

Comment: Thank you for your detective work Joe, I've added that and I'm still having the same problem though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think I've done it by removing the 1 from "#1" Joe thank you so much, I think you're a star

Comment: Since your page should always be at the top (since body's overflow is hidden), all of your links should be `<a href="#"`.